# How to read from external JSON and apply to navbar Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, bootstrap-4

Using [this](http://jsfiddle.net/saslam/vepeLmm0/) as a starting point, how can I alter it to read from an external data.json file? Im fairly new with JQuery. It works when if use

> var JSON =  {...same structure as from data.json...}

and gives me the expected result: a navbar structured after the json data.

My index.js and index.html

```js
import $, { type } from 'jquery'

try {
    var element = EMBED.getRootElement();
    var navbar = element.find("#navigationDiv");
    const userConfig = EMBED.getComponent().schema.data

    var json = userConfig.jsonfile.file // this is the file uploaded 
    json = (json.split(",").pop()); 
    console.log(json)
    json = atob(json)
    console.log(json)                    // prints out expected result, decoded json from base64

    function makeUL(lst, topLevelUl, rootLvl) {
        console.log("Make ul")
        var html = [];
        if (topLevelUl) {
            html.push('<ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="menu">');
            topLevelUl = false;
        } else {
            html.push('<ul class="submenu dropdown-menu" role="menu">');
        }
        $(lst).each(function () {
            html.push(makeLI(this, topLevelUl, rootLvl))
        });
        html.push('</ul>');
        rootLvl = true;
        return html.join("\n");
    }

    function makeLI(elem, topLevelUl, rootLvl) {
        console.log("make Li")
        var html = [];
        if (elem.children && !rootLvl) {
            html.push('<li class="dropdown-submenu dropdown">');
        } else {
            html.push('<li class="dropdown">');
            rootLvl = false;
        }
        //html.push(elem.link);
        if (elem.value) {
            html.push('<a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#' + elem.value + '"><i style="height:20px; width:20px;" class="' + elem.icon + '"></i>'  + elem.link + ' </a>');
            //<i style='height:20px; width:20px;' class='" + submenuData[i]["icon"] + "'></i>"
        }

        if (elem.children) {
            html.push(makeUL(elem.children, topLevelUl, rootLvl));
        }
        html.push('</li>');
        return html.join("\n");
    }

    $(function () {
        var topLevelUl = true;
        $(navbar).html(makeUL(JSON.menu, topLevelUl, true));
        console.log("lager meny")
        navbar.innerHTML = navbar;
        console.log(navbar)
    });
}
catch {
    console.log("error")
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
    <div id="navigationDiv" class="navbar-inner">
    </div>
</div>
```

and my data.json

```
{
  "menu": [
    {
      "id": 4,
      "link": "UnderGrad",
      "value": "undergrad.com",
      "icon": "fas fa-ban",
      "__domenu_params": {},
      "children": [
        {
          "id": 3,
          "link": "art.undergrad",
          "value": "art.undergrad.com",
          "icon": "fas fa-ban",
          "__domenu_params": {},
          "children": [
            {
              "id": 5,
              "link": "classic.art.undergrad",
              "value": "classic.art.undergrad.com",
              "icon": "fas fa-ban",
              "__domenu_params": {},
              "children": [
                {
                  "id": 5,
                  "link": "hey",
                  "value": "hey",
                  "icon": "fas fa-ban",
                  "__domenu_params": {}
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "link": "Grad",
      "value": "grad.com",
      "icon": "fas fa-ban",
      "__domenu_params": {},
      "children": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "link": "music.grad",
          "value": "music.grad.com",
          "icon": "fas fa-ban",
          "__domenu_params": {}
        },
        {
          "id": 6,
          "link": "science.grad",
          "value": "science.grad.com",
          "icon": "fas fa-ban",
          "__domenu_params": {}
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: if the json is external, than it is reasonable to assume that it is loaded asynchronously, which means you will need to use callbacks or promises; I'm not sure though, but you might want to check up on these topics :)

Comment: Do you have server-side code?  Is your html just a text file or is it generated somehow?  If it's generated, then you'll have an improved UX by include the json during the generation.  Otherwise you have: page-load (no menu), doc.ready starts to load json (still no menu) *then* menu loaded.  Your fiddle is very simple, but as soon as you load other resources the doc.ready gets pushed back (along with time to get/load the json) - you get quite a large FOUC.  I've simulated this for you:  http://jsfiddle.net/5eh4mj8L/

Comment: Also note that your fiddle doesn't have any JSON - it has a variable called "JSON" which is an object, not a string.  Your file will be a string.

Comment: @zedling the json printed in console on body load. The file itself is uploaded on a config site for the users, beforehand, so can I assume that is not the case?

Comment: No, that's exactly the case.  To change from an embedded object so that it loads an external file you need an ajax call - which, by definition, is asynchronous - the ajax call provides a callback when it's completed.

Comment: @freedomn-m There is more server side code. This is just for a widget on top of it. I saw your simulation, but it seems like its no issue in this case. I cant say for sure, since im in a dev env. But I will make a note of it. Thanks for feedback, got a working solution below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To load a json file use [jQuery.getJSON()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/).

To replace your code in your fiddle:

```
var JSON = { menu: [{ "id"...
$("#navigationDiv").html(makeUL(JSON.menu, topLevelUl, true));
```

you would use:

```
$.getJSON("data.json", function(data) {
    $("#navigationDiv").html(makeUL(data.menu, topLevelUl, true));  
});
```

where "data.json" is the url to your external json file

Comment: Thank you so much. I must say this was a very simple and efficent solution. The JSON is base64 encoded, but your solution make me able to skip the atob() as well.